# Как смапить адреса фронта и бэка?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, nginx, flask

Есть фронт на реакте, который шлет запросы на адрес `localhost:9000/api` + адрес api. И есть бэк на flask, который работает на адресе `localhost:3000`. Как мне смапить это между собой, чтобы запрос `localhost:9000/api/path` попадал в итоге на адрес `localhost:3000/path`?

Пробовал через nginx сделал так, но с таким конфигом дев-сервер пеакта вообще перестает запускаться.

```
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:9000;
    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }
}
```

Comment: Поставить nginx на порту 9000?

Comment: А вообще странно, нельзя ль на фронте предусмотреть какой-нибудь конфиг, в котором сразу прописать нужный адрес?

Comment: @andreymal не знаю, может и можно, но фронт писал не я и разобраться где там че с моим знанием js наверное невозможно.

Comment: @andreymal а про nginx я не понял. Сам фронт работает на 9000, а мне нужно перенаправить только запросы на 9000/api. А как так сделать на nginx?

Comment: что-нибудь в стиле `listen 9000; location / { отдать фронт; } location /api/ { proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/; }`

Comment: А во фронте порт 9000 точно захардкожен? Может, он использует относительные пути `/api` и можно без проблем запустить nginx на любом другом порту и проксировать через него фронт?

Comment: не, не захордкожен. Он обращается относительно. Но я не понимаю что значит "запустить nginx на любом другом порту и проксировать через него фронт"? Это как?

Comment: что-нибудь в стиле `listen 7777; location / { proxy_pass http://localhost:9000; } location /api/ { proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/; }`

Comment: И в браузере открывать `http://localhost:7777/` соответственно

Comment: @andreymal попробую

Comment: @andreymal  что-то я подумал и не понял все равно. От того, что я буду слушать 7777, ведь реакт на него обращаться не станет. И 7777/api/ довольно бесполезно получается перенаправлять на 3000 порт, потому что на него не будут запросы приходить. Или я не прав?

Comment: Если страница `http://localhost:7777/` обращается к относительному адресу `/api`, то запрос будет отправлен на `http://localhost:7777/api` и всё должно нормально работать. Если вы, конечно, не обманули и фронт действительно обращается именно к относительному адресу

Comment: приложение на React собираете с помощью webpack? на localhost:9000 крутится webpack dev server?

Comment: Склоняюсь к тому, что вопрос https://serverfault.com/a/379679 про ваш случай. Попробуйте конфиг в ответе, перепечатывать в коммент не стану, слишком громоздко, а приводить в качестве ответа - не пробовал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На случай, если оба ответа на комментарий будут "да":

у webpack dev server есть [конфиги проксирования](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy), вам нужно прописать в webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': 'http://localhost:3000'
    }
  }
};
```

Как можно заметить, пример из официальной документации должен подойти вам дословно.